# Vue, Vuetify is not properly initialized

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have setup `Vuetify` on my `Vue` webpack application.

My project is setup with `vue init webpack my-project` running `Vue 2.5.2` and using `Vuetify 2.0.2`.

I have installed `Vuetify` in my `App.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import '../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Everything seems to be working fine. I'm able to call `Vuetify`components in one of my components.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
        <v-card width="400" height="150" raised>
          <h4>Hello</h4>
        </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I then read that I need to wrap my `App.js` with the v-app component, but when I do that I get an error saying: `Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <NavigationBar />
      <v-content>
        <router-view />
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

Maybe `Vuetify` isn't installed correctly, I hope some of you can bring some light on my issue.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is lot of changes with new version.

try this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
vuetify : new Vuetify(),
...
});
```

good luck

Comment: In case someone ended up here like me from this blogpost: https://nordschool.com/create-a-blog-with-gridsome-and-vue/ the above solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 16):

I do it this way (vue 3.9, vuetify 2.0)

In main.js (or App.js)

```
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
...
new Vue({
  ...
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib"

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md',  // 'mdi' || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4'
  },
  theme: {
    dark: false,
  },
  themes: {
    light: {
      primary: "#4682b4",
      secondary: "#b0bec5",
      accent: "#8c9eff",
      error: "#b71c1c",
    },
  },
})
```

in App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: I did that, but got an new error.

./node_modules/css-loader??ref--9-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--9-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--9-3!./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass
Module build failed: 
undefined
   ^
      Invalid CSS after "    @content": expected "}", was "($material-light); "

Comment: It looks like a css error in your file, check syntax

Comment: @dumbprogrammer - As per the quickstart guide, ensure you have sass and sass-loader installed. Also double check you have 'sass' and not 'node-sass'

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object

$ yarn add sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
// OR
$ npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D

Answer (score 10):

If you are using vue-cli, Add these lines to file index.html after meta tags:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And your main.js should look like this:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Vuetify)
export default new Vuetify({ })

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Patrice has one of my preferred finely tailored answers, depending on configuration, this may be what you need:

```
webpack | vue 2.5+ | vuetify 2.1+
```

In your main.js/App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

//Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
vuetify,
});
```

In your plugins/vuetify.js

```
// resources/js/plugins/vuetify.js

import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md', // default - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

In your `EaxmpleComponent.vue` and all other vue files:
Wrap all vue components in v-app and template tag like:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered same issue.

```
vuetify@2.3.2
vue@2.6.11
nuxt@2.13.0
+ typescript
```

I got solved with below.

**[layouts/default.vue]**

```
<script  lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

@Component({
  vuetify:new Vuetify()
})
export default class extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

---

if you not typescript
below helps you.

```
<script>
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

export default {
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
const opts = {
  theme: {
    dark: true,
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '...',
        ...
      },
      dark: {
        primary: '...',
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

to your `main.js`.

Answer (score 1):

When adding vuetify (2.x) to gridsome, I had the same problem and had to add the vuetify import object to appOptions in main.js:

```
appOptions.vuetify = new Vuetify({})
```

as described in:

https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome.org/blob/master/docs/assets-css.md

and

https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/603#issuecomment-567056678

Answer (score -2):

Below link Helped me.

https://www.codetd.com/en/article/7261224

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index'
import store from './store/index'

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vuetify)
// vuetify 自定义配置
export default new Vuetify({})

new Vue({
router,
store,
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')