# Is it possible to include vuetify in a library bundle?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two Vue projects, one is an app that is injected in an older website via script-tag and a second project, that is a form, that uses own logic and vuetify components. The later should be used in other projects also and gets props from where it is used. Therefore it should be compiled as a library.

If i compile it as app i can transfer data via a global JS variable, but i would like to use the components like any other library. (Just import it and put it in the `<template>` like so: `<MyComponent ..props../>`)
If i compile it as a library i got all sorts of vuetify not correctly initialized. After i cleared them my HTML looked excactly like my code (eg:`<v-app>...</v-app>`) without any errors. 
The 'serve' from the standard installation worked without a problem in the component project.

The component project is created with `vue create project` and modified according to https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library

I already searched online and got only so far, my question on the vue discord was left unanswered, so my questions are:
1. Is this even possible to do?
2. If it is, could you please point me in a direction, or give a summary of what i have to do?
3. If not, is there another way of achieving this, except for copying the raw code into each project?

Comment: It's best to rephrase this question with a simplified version of your code, see this question as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291304/vue-vuetify-is-not-properly-initialized

Comment: @ellisdod Thanks for the reply, but at this moment I am not sure if it is a problem with my code, but if this kind of behavior is achievable and if so if I am trying the correct way. Are you impling this is doable? Because I havent found anything regarding this online, maybe I just used the wrong search terms? I am after all pretty new to Vue.  
I dont know how i could rephrase my question, if something is unclear, i can try to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes. Is it recommended, no.

The best way to do this is to export your form component as a library so that it can be imported into other projects but exclude any dependencies like Vuetify, which should be imported separately. This avoids versioning errors.

The Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html) on packaging for npm are useful as is this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-publish-your-vuejs-component-on-npm)

Comment: I feared this was the case. So unless theres a way to bundle this project without dependencies (and importing those in the other projects) I'll just copy the unbundled files.  I'll look into those links you provided and even if it doesnt solve my problem I learned something.

Comment: It is certainly possible to bundle without dependencies.