# Vuetify v-data-table Error in render: "TypeError: _a is undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, vuetify.js, apollo

I am trying to bind v-data-table to my returned WorkOrders query from graphene-django graphQL.

In my `App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="home">
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="workorders">
    </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const WorkOrderQuery = gql`
 query c {
  workorders {
   id,
   description,
   relatedCustomer {
    customerName
   }
   serviceTechnician {
    username
   }
  }
 }
`;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Customer',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'relatedCustomer.customerName'
        }
      ],
      workorders: [],
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    workorders: WorkOrderQuery,
  },
}
</script>
```

I can confirm that the query (when queried using GraphiQL/postman/insomnia) returns a valid list of dictionaries.  Example response from the above query:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "workorders": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "description": "yoooo",
        "relatedCustomer": {
          "customerName": "Joe"
        },
        "serviceTechnician": {
          "username": "joe"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "description": "yoooo",
        "relatedCustomer": {
          "customerName": "Joe"
        },
        "serviceTechnician": {
          "username": "user1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "description": "yoooo",
        "relatedCustomer": {
          "customerName": "Joe"
        },
        "serviceTechnician": {
          "username": "user1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting in Developer Tools is

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _a is undefined"

found in

---> <VData>
       <VDataTable>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

But I can confirm that the query at /graphql/ is returning a valid response:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "workorders": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "description": "yoooo",
                "relatedCustomer": {
                    "customerName": "Joe",
                    "__typename": "CustomerType"
                },
                "serviceTechnician": {
                    "username": "joe",
                    "__typename": "UserNode"
                },
                "__typename": "WorkOrderType"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "description": "yoooo",
                "relatedCustomer": {
                    "customerName": "Joe",
                    "__typename": "CustomerType"
                },
                "serviceTechnician": {
                    "username": "user1",
                    "__typename": "UserNode"
                },
                "__typename": "WorkOrderType"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "description": "yoooo",
                "relatedCustomer": {
                    "customerName": "Joe",
                    "__typename": "CustomerType"
                },
                "serviceTechnician": {
                    "username": "user1",
                    "__typename": "UserNode"
                },
                "__typename": "WorkOrderType"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And using the Vue developer tools extension, can also verify that `workorders` array is being set correctly to the three objects returned from the above query.

I'm brand new to Vuetify/Vue, so I would really appreciate some pointers here on how to go about handling my headers, as well as what is going wrong or what the TypeError _a means.

Thanks for any and all input.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to be a configuration error, after wrapping everything in `<v-app>` I got an error telling me Vuetify was not being properly initialized.

After looking it up, I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291304/vue-vuetify-is-not-properly-initialized) showing how to properly initialize Vuetify.

In my case, I needed to add `vuetify: new Vuetify()` inside my Vue instantiation.